# BMI Calculator with 2 decimals

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a BMI calculator.
I don't know how to make it to show the result with 2 decimals (`21.64` for example).

Here is my code:

```
taille = float(input("Enter votre taille en mètre: "))

poids = float(input("Enter votre poids en kg: "))

bmi = (poids/(taille**2))


print ('Votre IMC est', bmi, 'et vous êtes :')



if ( bmi < 16):
   print("maigre, veuillez consulter un spécialiste !")

elif ( bmi >= 16 and bmi < 18.5):
   print(" sous le seuil normal,Faites du sport et manger sainement !")

elif ( bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25):
   print("en bonne santé, continuez comme ça!")

elif ( bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30):
   print("en surpoids, faites un peu plus de sport !")

elif ( bmi >=30):
   print("sévèrement en surpoids, faites du sport et manger sainement")
```

Comment: Replace `bmi` with `round(bmi, 2)` in your first print call.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
a = 15.65463857
print('%.2f'%a)
```

Output:

```
>>>15.65
```

Comment: or `print('Votre IMC est {:.2f}'.format(a))`

Comment: Thanks a lot man !

Comment: Also , if you have more time i wanted to add , like we respond to the questions, they ask if you want to restart , you put yes, or if u put no it close the program.. how can i make it ?